# C# Design Pattern to permit-restrict content to users

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am using ASP.NET MVC to develop a website for order entry. The orders are not just about buying a product but about building a new customized product given the available product parts.

With MVC is kind of intuitive to restrict permissions to actions. For example, only admins can create new product parts (e.g., call the action CreateNewWheel). Users on the other hand can call the action BindExistingWheelToMyNewCar.

HOWEVER, is there a design pattern to restrict access to content? I need to give permission to content itself that is going to be displayed, not actions that can be executed.

I guess that I can always start creating database relationships here and there based on user roles. But my question is: Is there an existing design pattern that covers this scenario and that I can use as a guide? I want to get as complex as permit, restrict, and inherit permissions that will allow to define which product parts will be presented to end users.

Any hint will be useful.

Thanks,

Comment: What you are asking for sounds like [Resource based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased). This tutorial is for ASP.NET Core, but should be applicable to ASP.NET as well.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: The pattern you are looking for is Protection Proxy.